# Why numpy.asarray() doesn't work properly with large number of arrays?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy, multidimensional-array

I have a problem with `numpy.asarray()` and is that just can't convert a list of arrays to a matrix properly when I work with a large number of arrays. For example, with a list of six arrays (each one with a length of (5000,)) with `numpy.asarray()`, it can be converted to a matrix of (6,5000) and that's what I need, but when I use 1285 arrays, numpy just doesn't generate the matrix of (1285,5000), instead, leave the list of (1285,) length, what's going on? Post the code and examples to explain better, the main section that has the problem:

```
ecg_filenames_train_gridsearch=ecg_filenames[folds[0][1]]
ecg_train_timeseries=[]
for names in ecg_filenames_train_gridsearch:
    data, header_data = pc.load_challenge_data(names,'I')
    data = data[:5000]#truncate arrays to a max length of 5000
    ecg_train_timeseries.append(data)
X_train_gridsearch = np.asarray(ecg_train_timeseries)
X_train_gridsearch = X_train_gridsearch.reshape(ecg_filenames_train_gridsearch.shape[0],5000,1)#Here I get a
 ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 1285 into shape (1285,5000,1)
```

Test I made with few data (6 1D-arrays, length of (5000,) each one):

```
print(X_train_gridsearch)

RESULT:
[[  24.   24.   29. ...   24.   24.   24.]
 [4302. 4136. 3999. ... 3897. 3880. 3893.]
 [ -35.  -35.  -35. ...  -40.  -40.  -40.]
 [-245. -243. -242. ... -146. -134. -128.]
 [-474. -444. -456. ... -410. -453. -458.]
 [  28.   39.   45. ... -310. -361. -403.]]
```

```
print(X_train_gridsearch.shape)
(6,5000)
```

Test with all the data I need to use(1285 1D-arrays, length of (5000,) each one):

```
print(X_train_gridsearch)

RESULT:
[array([88., 88., 87., ...,  8.,  9., 10.])
 array([43., 58., 44., ..., -5.,  3.,  0.])
 array([-8., -9., -8., ..., -9., -8., -8.]) ...
 array([-30., -30., -30., ..., -50., -50., -50.])
 array([ 205.,  205.,  205., ..., -120., -120., -120.])
 array([ -40.,  -40.,  -40., ..., -110., -110., -110.])]
```

```
print(X_train_gridsearch.shape)
(1285,)
```

In the first case, np.asarray() convert the arrays from a list of arrays into a matrix, but in the second one, it just keep `array[]` format, what's wrong? Hope you can help me.

Comment: try `np.stack(ecg_train_timeseries)`

Comment: Have you verified that all the arrays have length 5000?  If the length of even one is less than 5000, you'll get a 1-d object array instead of a 2-d array.

Comment: @hpaulj I'll try that

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser with `data = data[:5000]` I truncate all arrays to a length of 5000, but I'll verify that too.

Comment: That works if you know that all the input arrays have length at least 5000.  If an input array has length, say, 4997, then `data[:5000]` will not generate an error, and will return an array with length 4997.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser you are right, one single array has a length of 4999 :( that generated the problem, how can I add a 0 to get a length of 5000?

Answer (score 0):

I solved just adding this lines to my code:

```
if data.shape<(5000,):
    a = np.resize(data,(5000,))
    data = a
```

Before `.append()`, thanks everyone and Warren.